# HTML Navigation Error. How to handle www.website.com versus website.com? Correct navigation in html?

Tags: html, navigation, no-www

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="page">
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="http://MyOwnWebsite.com/">Home</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="page1.html">page1</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="page2.html">page2</a>
</div>
```

When i browse to www.MyOwnWebsite.com and then click on the navigation links, all works as expected.

But if i browse to MYOWnWebsite.com (no www) and then try to navigate to one of the pages i recieve a error :

```
Firefox can't find the file at http://MyOWnWebsite.com/page1.html.
```

Am i doing something wrong? what is the correct way to handle www.website.com versus website.com?

Comment: that depends on your server. Did you setup both locations on your server configuration?

Comment: I am unsure.  Both work (with www and without), but the navigation gets screwy.

if i change page1.html to www.mywebsite.com/page1.html it stacks and tries to go to mywebsite.com/www.mywebsite.com/mypage1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this i did the following:

Went into my host gator control panel ->
Clicked on domain redirect.
added a permanent redirect from http://website.com to redirect to https://www.mysite.com.

This way every time the user goes mysite.com without the www , it will redirect them to the www.mysite.com and all the navigation will work from there.

Comment: You can simply direct them both to the same IP, and there'll be no redirect. It will simply load the same webpage.

As I said.

Comment: where abouts would that be in a control panel? whats the name of the service that would hold these settings?

Comment: Where is this setting located?

Comment: In your domain's registrar's or reseller's control panel.
DNS records/settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root (and ssh) access to your webhost, you should add a symbolic link to your www folder, in the htdocs directory. All directories in your htdocs folder are considered subdomains by your webserver. So if your DNS record points you to your server for the wildcard subdomain, your webserver will handle further processing of subdomains. So this symbolic link will make your server to load the same content for www.mysite.com and mysite.com.

```
cd /patch/to/htdocs
ln -s www mysite
```

Replace mysite by your domain name, but without the country suffix and www prefix. It should give you something like this:

```
[vhostxxxx@ssh:~/domains/mysite.com/htdocs]$ ls -l
total 3 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 vhostxxxx vhostuser  3 2012-11-10 12:47 mysite -> www
drwxr-xr-x+ 9 vhostxxxx vhostuser 20 2012-11-13 21:52 www`
```

Now, if I would browse to mysite.com, I would see the same site as www.mysite.com.

As for linking in your navigation:

```
`<div id="page">
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="http://mysite.com/">Home</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="http://wwww.mysite.com">Home</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="wwww.mysite.com">Home</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="page1.html">page1</a>
    <a class="topNavigationLink" href="/page2.html">page2</a>
</div>`
```

This will link as follows (in some order):

1. To the directory (or symbolic link) called `mysite` in your `htdocs`
2. To the directory (or symbolic link) called `wwww` in your `htdocs`
3. This is wrong. It will point at a page called `wwww.mysite.com`, which then should be located in the same directory as the page you linked it from. So if you linked it from `htdocs/www/index.html` it will point to `htdocs/www/wwww.mysite.com`. Always use `http://` if your address includes a domain.
4. To the page called `page1.html`, located in the same directory as the page you linked it from. If you linked it from `htdocs/www/SomeTopic/page99.html` it will point to `htdocs/www/SomeTopic/page1.html`
5. To the page called `page2.html`, located in the document root. If you linked it from `htdocs/www/SomeTopic/page99.html` it will point to `htdocs/www/page1.html`

Comment: good explanation except all those prompt commands.  i just changed a redirect from mysite.copm to www.mysite.com and it fixed the problem.  all pages are located in one big giant file.  I am not using IIS so my htdocs folder is non existant (or at least from my view using host gator)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is to **use relative links.**

That being said, you **should** check your **domain's DNS records**, A records to have **A "*" record**, which takes all your subdomains, including "www" and points them at your server.

Or if you don't need all, you can put just "www".

You do this in your **registrar**'s control panel.

What you have in your navigation are links without leading forward slash.

MAke your relative links `/page_x.html` and not just `page_x.html`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one common mistake with navigation, when you are in at the current url

> `http://www.mywebsite.com/home/index.html`

and you have an anchor tag in this form:

> `<a class="topNavigationLink" href="page1.html">page1</a>`

When you click on this link, you are redirected to:

> `http://www.mywebsite.com/home/page1.html`

This is because `href="page1.html"` is a **relative link**, and the base of the url is `/home/`

## Solution:

if you want to access :

> `http://www.mywebsite.com/home/page1.html`

You will have to add a forward slash to your link. Example:

> `<a class="topNavigationLink" href="/page1.html">page1</a>`

This will have a base of the root domain `/`